# Read real time raw data bluetooth

Tags: audio, bluetooth

Currently im working on a bluetooth speaker, which has to receive audio via bluetooth from my phone. The bluetooth receiver will be the raspberry pi 3 a+, and it will direct the audio data to an amplifier. 
The point is that before the raspberry pi outputs the audio data, I want to digitally process the audio data and after that I want to send it to the output.

My question is: How can I get to the raw bluetooth data input from my raspberry pi, and direct it to my dsp programm?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What type of DSP do you have in mind... is this an existing package, or will you write your own? Have you done a search to learn how others are doing audio DSP for Raspberry Pi?

Comment: The problem here is not the DSP. The DSP program already works on the raspberry pi. The program detects the beat and outputs the song with an overlaying emphasized beat, where the program has a wave file input.

Comment: The next step is to use the live data-stream of the bluetooth as an input for the DSP program. The problem however is, that I don't know exactly how I would acces the bluetooth data that is coming from the phone, and direct this to the DSP.

Comment: [PulseAudio](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/) is one package available for the RPi. Have you looked at that?

Comment: Now i sent the data to a "fifo_output" pipe file, with the help of pulseaudio command  "load-module module-pipe-sink". I am able to play this, however is their a way to read the content of this file?